# PyInstaller can't find PyYAML hidden import

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyyaml

I am using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) to freeze a script that depends on [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org).

I was getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'yaml'
```

So I included `yaml` as a hidden import, but PyInstaller can't import it.

```
$ pyinstaller myapp.spec
...
2515 DEBUG: Hidden import: yaml
2516 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'yaml'
2516 ERROR: Hidden import 'yaml' not found
...
```

So running my binary still fails with the same error.

PyYAML is installed on the active virtual environment, as other modules that don't fail when included on hidden imports. I've also tried to install it globally and even to install the `python-yaml` system package (Debian).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it installing the `python3-yaml` system package. My mistake was to install the Python2 version.

Comment: It did not work for me ! I am still investigating.
The binary works in the host where it was built, but not on others.